# python pytesseract OCR PDF Table data

Tags: python, nlp, ocr, python-tesseract

I am working on OCR text recognition from PDF documents. I am using pytesseract to achieve it. I am close to my result, but I see a challenge when data is in Tabular format in PDF document.

For example

[image]

I have used below code to extract text data from pdf page.

`pytesseract.image_to_string(img)`

Below is the function result.

```
Colt Col2 Col3

This is a very Short text | Another long
long line of text line of text
T lind Common in

math
```

Expected output should be as below

```
Col1
This is a very long line of text
PI
Col2
Short text
1 in 5
Col3
Another long line of text
Common in math
```

Could anyone help me how to identify the tabular data from pdf document and extract data as above format.

Thanks in advance.